# Returning a custom type

Tags: kotlin, data-class

I have access to a library, but I don't want to fork the code and maintain the library, because I am too new to Kotlin.

The code looks like this:

```
data class Foo<out T: Baz>(val foos: ..., bars: ...)
```

I can call methods from the library to get back a `Foo`, but I need that `Foo` to implement `Serializable` from `java.io`. I asked someone how might I do this, and they suggested that I extend from the data class. Is this the right course of action, and if so, how might one go about it?

Comment: You can't extend from data class. Welcome to Kotlin.

Comment: No, it's not th right course of action. If *you* need to serialize something, *you* should define your own serializable class containing what must be serialized. Not rely on some library to provide what you need. Create your own class, and transform Foo instances to instances of your own serializable class.

Comment: You can create your own data class with the field you need and that is Serializable, and create a mapper to map Foo to your data class. Your code will be cleaner and you can change the library you're using by changing the mapper and not all of your code later.

Answer (score 0):

In Kotlin you can't make class implement interface which it doesn't implement (unlike Haskell and Go).

Sore your options are folowing:

- Create your own class implementing Serializable which has all the same fields as basic. Then you can even create constructor in new class which accepts basic class as argument
- Use another way of serialization, for example [kotlinx.serialization](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization)